# Altair saver - frequent errors saving charts

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, altair

I've been getting frequent but not constant errors using Altair saver to save .png files via selenium and chromedriver. First I get a "headless chrome" error:

> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of
> page crash from unknown error: cannot determine loading status from
> tab crashed (Session info: headless chrome=90.0.4430.212)

Followed by a "invalid session" error when I try to save it again:

> InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id

Based on my read of StackOverflow and elsewhere, the initial error leaves a chromedriver session open and that causes the second error. It will resolve itself if I close out of everything and reopen but that's not really a workable solution. Any advice on making saving Altair charts more reliable?

Versions are up to date and compatible as far as I know: altair 4.1.0, altair-saver 0.5.0, selenium 3.141.0, Chrome 90.0.4430.212, ChromeDriver 90.0.4430.24, chromedriver-binary 90.0.4430.24.0

Full trackback of headless chrome error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-cf20dd94d732> in <module>

---> 30 chart.save('chart.png', scale_factor=3)

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\[...]\lib\site-packages\altair\vegalite\v4\api.py in save(self, fp, format, override_data_transformer, scale_factor, vegalite_version, vega_version, vegaembed_version, **kwargs)
    474         if override_data_transformer:
    475             with data_transformers.disable_max_rows():
--> 476                 result = save(**kwds)
    477         else:
    478             result = save(**kwds)

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\[...]\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\save.py in save(chart, fp, vega_version, vegaembed_version, format, mode, vegalite_version, embed_options, json_kwds, webdriver, scale_factor, **kwargs)
    119             webdriver=webdriver,
    120             scale_factor=scale_factor,
--> 121             **kwargs,
    122         )
    123         if format == "png":

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\[...]\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\mimebundle.py in spec_to_mimebundle(spec, format, mode, vega_version, vegaembed_version, vegalite_version, **kwargs)
     58                 "see http://github.com/altair-viz/altair_saver/".format(fmt=format)
     59             )
---> 60         return altair_saver.render(spec, format, mode=mode, **kwargs)
     61     if format == "html":
     62         html = spec_to_html(

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\[...]\lib\site-packages\altair_saver\_core.py in render(chart, fmts, mode, embed_options, method, **kwargs)
    255         Saver = _select_saver(method, mode=mode, fmt=fmt)
    256         saver = Saver(spec, mode=mode, embed_options=embed_options, **kwargs)
--> 257         mimebundle.update(saver.mimebundle(fmt))
    258 
    259     return mimebundle

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\[...]\lib\site-packages\altair_saver\savers\_saver.py in mimebundle(self, fmts)
     88                 vegalite_version=self._package_versions["vega-lite"],
     89             )
---> 90             bundle[mimetype] = self._serialize(fmt, "mimebundle")
     91         return bundle
     92 

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\[...]\lib\site-packages\altair_saver\savers\_selenium.py in _serialize(self, fmt, content_type)
    282 
    283     def _serialize(self, fmt: str, content_type: str) -> MimebundleContent:
--> 284         out = self._extract(fmt)
    285         if fmt == "png":
    286             assert isinstance(out, str)

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\[...]\lib\site-packages\altair_saver\savers\_selenium.py in _extract(self, fmt)
    262 
    263         url = self._serve(html, js_resources)
--> 264         driver.get("about:blank")
    265         driver.get(url)
    266         try:

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\[...]\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in get(self, url)
    331         Loads a web page in the current browser session.
    332         """
--> 333         self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
    334 
    335     @property

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\[...]\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\[...]\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
  (Session info: headless chrome=90.0.4430.212)
```

And invalid session error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidSessionIdException                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-cf20dd94d732> in <module>
     29 
---> 30 chart.save('chart.png' scale_factor=3)

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\[...]\lib\site-packages\altair\vegalite\v4\api.py in save(self, fp, format, override_data_transformer, scale_factor, vegalite_version, vega_version, vegaembed_version, **kwargs)
    474         if override_data_transformer:
    475             with data_transformers.disable_max_rows():
--> 476                 result = save(**kwds)
    477         else:
    478             result = save(**kwds)

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\[...]\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\save.py in save(chart, fp, vega_version, vegaembed_version, format, mode, vegalite_version, embed_options, json_kwds, webdriver, scale_factor, **kwargs)
    119             webdriver=webdriver,
    120             scale_factor=scale_factor,
--> 121             **kwargs,
    122         )
    123         if format == "png":

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\[...]\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\mimebundle.py in spec_to_mimebundle(spec, format, mode, vega_version, vegaembed_version, vegalite_version, **kwargs)
     58                 "see http://github.com/altair-viz/altair_saver/".format(fmt=format)
     59             )
---> 60         return altair_saver.render(spec, format, mode=mode, **kwargs)
     61     if format == "html":
     62         html = spec_to_html(

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\[...]\lib\site-packages\altair_saver\_core.py in render(chart, fmts, mode, embed_options, method, **kwargs)
    255         Saver = _select_saver(method, mode=mode, fmt=fmt)
    256         saver = Saver(spec, mode=mode, embed_options=embed_options, **kwargs)
--> 257         mimebundle.update(saver.mimebundle(fmt))
    258 
    259     return mimebundle

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\[...]\lib\site-packages\altair_saver\savers\_saver.py in mimebundle(self, fmts)
     88                 vegalite_version=self._package_versions["vega-lite"],
     89             )
---> 90             bundle[mimetype] = self._serialize(fmt, "mimebundle")
     91         return bundle
     92 

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\[...]\lib\site-packages\altair_saver\savers\_selenium.py in _serialize(self, fmt, content_type)
    282 
    283     def _serialize(self, fmt: str, content_type: str) -> MimebundleContent:
--> 284         out = self._extract(fmt)
    285         if fmt == "png":
    286             assert isinstance(out, str)

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\[...]\lib\site-packages\altair_saver\savers\_selenium.py in _extract(self, fmt)
    262 
    263         url = self._serve(html, js_resources)
--> 264         driver.get("about:blank")
    265         driver.get(url)
    266         try:

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\[...]\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in get(self, url)
    331         Loads a web page in the current browser session.
    332         """
--> 333         self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
    334 
    335     @property

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\[...]\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\[...]\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id
```

Comment: You can try using nodejs instead of selenium, it is installed automatically if you use conda, otherwise you can install it via `npm` https://github.com/altair-viz/altair_saver/#nodejs